# Main class not found when using Manifest jar with JavaExec in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jhipster, gatling

I have the below gradle script from the [Jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) framework. It is used to run Gatling tests and due to the command line limit on windows I have tried using a manifest only jar approach. A detailed discussion regarding this can be found here [Jhipster issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1514)
 But the below script seems to generate the Manifest jar properly but JavaExec is unable to find the main class, some pointer on this would be really helpfull. A console log of error is below as well

I have posted this on the gradle forum [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/main-class-not-found-when-using-manifest-jar-with-javaexec/10179), but no luck so far

apply plugin: 'scala'

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/gatling/simulations']
            output.classesDir = 'target/test-classes'
        }
    }
}
task manifestJar(dependsOn:'compileTestScala',type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    classifier 'pathing'
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            // uri is just needed for Windows-compatibility
            attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect{ project.uri(it) }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
task gatlingRun(dependsOn:'manifestJar', type: JavaExec) {
    //dependsOn configurations.runtime
    group = "gatling"

    standardInput = System.in

    final def sourceSet = sourceSets.test
    File configFile = file('src/test/gatling/conf/gatling.conf')

    def String gatlingDataFolder = "$project.rootDir.absolutePath/src/test/gatling/data"
    def String gatlingReportsFolder = "$project.buildDir.absolutePath/reports/gatling"
    def String gatlingBodiesFolder = "$project.rootDir.absolutePath/src/test/gatling/bodies"
    def String gatlingSimulationsFolder = "$project.rootDir.absolutePath/src/test/gatling/simulations"

    //classpath sourceSet.output + sourceSet.runtimeClasspath + files("src/test/gatling/conf")
    classpath sourceSet.output + files(manifestJar.archivePath) + files("src/test/gatling/conf")
    //classpath = files(pathingJar.archivePath)
    main = "io.gatling.app.Gatling"

    environment GATLING_HOME:''

    args '-df', gatlingDataFolder
    args '-rf', gatlingReportsFolder
    args '-bdf', gatlingBodiesFolder
    args "-sf", gatlingSimulationsFolder
    args "-rd", ""

}
```

**Console log:**

```
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.973 secs.
:compileTestScala (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:compileTestScala
Skipping task ':compileTestScala' as it is up-to-date (took 0.325 secs).
:compileTestScala UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestScala (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.344 secs.
:manifestJar (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:manifestJar
Skipping task ':manifestJar' as it is up-to-date (took 0.012 secs).
:manifestJar UP-TO-DATE
:manifestJar (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.038 secs.
:processTestResources (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:processTestResources
Skipping task ':processTestResources' as it is up-to-date (took 0.013 secs).
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.041 secs.
:testClasses (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:testClasses
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.019 secs.
:gatlingRun (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:gatlingRun
Executing task ':gatlingRun' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe''. Working directory: D:\Projects\jh5 Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.
0_45\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=SG -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp D:\Projects\jh5\target\test-classes;D:\Projects
\jh5\build\resources\test;D:\Projects\jh5\build\libs\jhipster-pathing.jar;D:\Projects\jh5\src\test\gatling\conf io.gatling.app.Gatling -df D:\Projects
\jh5/src/test/gatling/data -rf D:\Projects\jh5\build/reports/gatling -bdf D:\Projects\jh5/src/test/gatling/bodies -sf D:\Projects\jh5/src/test/gatling
/simulations -rd
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe''
Error: Could not find or load main class io.gatling.app.Gatling
:gatlingRun FAILED
:gatlingRun (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.166 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gatlingRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.134 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Comment: AFAIK, the classpath of a manifest in a jar is only useful when using `java -jar thejar.jar`. If you specify a classpath using -cp and a main class to execute, it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
Your manifest jar contains the wrong classpath. Try using `testCompile` files:

```
task manifestJar(dependsOn:'compileTestScala',type: Jar) {
dependsOn configurations.testCompile
archiveName 'gatlingBooter.jar'
doFirst {
    manifest {
        // uri is just needed for Windows-compatibility
        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.testCompile.files.collect{ project.uri(it) }.join(' ')
       }
   }
}
```

---

OLD:

If the manifest jar only works `java -jar` @Deepu maybe we should try the following:

```
task runJar(dependsOn:jar) << {
  javaexec { main="-jar"; args jar.archivePath } 
}
```

At least it looks good. Will try to test it during the weekend.

References:

- http://blog.denevell.org/gradle-run-jar-file.html
- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1274

Comment: For a simple jar file it works fine. But the complex use case with the scala compiler doesn't work. I think it is still the best to wait for the next gatling release :(

Comment: Damn then i guess i have to switch to maven for this alone :( coz i need to finish the project by this month, @atomfrede is there way to trigger a maven goal from gradle?

Comment: Never tried it but at least you should be able to invoke mvn via the command line from gradle.