# Build jar with gradle in IntelliJ. Main class could not be found or loaded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following problem: I am using IntelliJ Idea with gradle. I can build the jar without any problems, but I get the error that the main class could not be found or loaded when executing the jar with *java -jar*.

I don't think that its a version clash, as the java version in the IDE matches my version that I use in the console.

The path to the code is the standard path for gradle projects, so src/main/java.
The interesting part of the *build.gradle* looks like this:

```
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Implementation_Group_C',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'EchoServer'
   }

    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task fatJar(type: Jar){
    manifest.from jar.manifest
    classifier = 'all'
    from {
       configurations.runtime.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    } {
     exclude 'META_INF/*.SF'
     exclude 'META_INF/*.DSA'
     exclude 'META_INF/*.RSA'
    }
    with jar
}
```

When I inspect the jar, I find that the EchoServer.class is in the main directory (should be correct, as its dir is */src/main/java/EchoServer.java*) and the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Implementation_Group_C
Implementation-Version: 1.1-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: EchoServer
```

Looks fine to me, but still i get the error that the main class could not be found or loaded.
I would be really thankful if someone could help me out here.

Comment: I see you have taken it from my other answer, I have stated that this approach is not a good practice, btw your main is in a default package which is not good either. Please familiarize with the `application` plugin in Gradle, which meant to build you a runnable archive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main class not found when using Manifest jar with JavaExec in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218278/main-class-not-found-when-using-manifest-jar-with-javaexec-in-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EchoServer (which really shouldn't be in the default package, BTW: this is bad practice) seems to depend on classes found in libraries, but these libraries are not in the classpath. So the class can't be loaded.

Java does **NOT** load jar files inside the jar file. It loads classes from jar files **outside** of the jar file, if they are in the classpath:

- either by adding all jar files in the classpath using `java -cp yourjar.jar:library1.jar:library2.jar EchoServer`
- or by using `java -jar yourjar.jar` if the libraries are specified in the classpath inside the manifest. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

So, in short, fat jars can't work unless the main class inside the jar file is a custom class loader that reads other classes from the bundles jar files. Note that gradle has an application plugin to create a standard Java application zip file, with all the libraries, and scripts to start the app.

Comment: unfortunately i got the same problem when trying to add the dependencies to the class path. I solved it using the shadow plugin for gradle. I don't really know why it works, because from my perspective not much has changed, but it works. The application plugin does it too, so i will mark this answer as correct because of this. Thanks